# Can Facebook's Graph Search be used to analyse Facebook friends by gender?

Tags: facebook, facebook-search, facebook-graph-search

[The article here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-egg-followers/28782/) seems to suggest that Facebook's Graph Search is powerful enough to analyse Facebook friends by gender.

I'm aware that using the search term `"My friends that are male"`, for example, will *list* my Facebook friends that are male, but this doesn't compare both genders, nor does it seem to even count the male friends listed.

**Is what the article alludes to possible, and if so, how would it be accomplished?**